# Why do I need FreeGLUT to compile and link a GLFW program

Tags: c++, opengl

I have compiled and linked a simple OpenGL program. It is a C++ console program, which prints the version number. It works, but I don't understand why it works. Please can you help me to understand it.

I have linked in both the GLFW and FreeGLUT libraries. I thought that these were alternative toolkits. However, if I take out the FreeGLUT library, glGetString doesn't link anymore.

Are they alternative toolkits? Why do I need to link in FreeGLUT? Am I missing a library which I should link instead?

```
// GLVersion.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "glfw3.h"
#include "glfw3native.h"
#include "freeglut.h"
#include "glut.h"


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    const GLubyte *Vstr;
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* mywindow = glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"GLFW",NULL,NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mywindow);

    Vstr = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    fprintf(stderr, "Your OpenGL version is %s\n", Vstr);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glGetString` is an OpenGL function, not a GLU function. To link with it, you must link with `OpenGL32.lib`.

Comment: Thank you. I now have the following linker data in Visual Studio 2015: glfw3.lib;glfw3dll.lib;opengl32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies). The above example compiles and links OK (so do I need to bring in FreeGLUT at all)?

Comment: If I add new lines of code, such as glClearColor, that works OK as well. If I add glShaderSource, it compiles but does not link that function, or others like it. I've used the same link libraries. Have I missed a library?

Comment: @FrancisKing You'll need to use an OpenGL function loader for most functions. There are many loaders to choose from, like glew, glxw, gl3w or glLoadGen.